# AngularJS custom filter and reset view

Tags: angularjs

I have the following filter function in my controller and it works. The issue is that I have several buttons that call the same function and filter by a different perf_no. So if I click the first button, great. The filter works but as soon as I click the second button, it doesn't. Now I know why (I think), and that is since the first button click filtered the view, the second button's perf_no no longer exists in the view. I think I either need not to filter the view directly or reset the view which I don't know how to do.

```
this.myFunc = function (perfNo) {
                var myFilter = this.perfs.filter(function (el) { return (el.perf_no === perfNo); });
                console.log(myFilter);
                this.perfs = myFilter;
                return myFilter;
```

Controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('perfList', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);

(function (app) {
    'use strict';

    app.component('perfList', {
        templateUrl: 'perf-list.templateV3.html',
        //filter: function monthFilter() {
        //    alert("I am a Filter");
        //},



        controller: function PerfListController() {

            this.perfs = [
      { "perf_no": "1555", "perf_desc": "Test1"},
      { "perf_no": "1599", "perf_desc": "Test2"},
      { "perf_no": "1600", "perf_desc": "Test3" }
            ];


            this.myFunc = function (perfNo) {
                var myFilter = this.perfs.filter(function (el) { return (el.perf_no === perfNo); });
                console.log(myFilter);
                this.perfs = myFilter;
                return myFilter;



            }

        }
    });
})(myApp);
```

html template

```
<div class="container-fluid" >
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <span class="cs-span-nav" ng-click="$ctrl.myFunc('1555')">Click one</span>
        <span class="cs-span-nav" ng-click="$ctrl.myFunc('1599')">Click two</span>
    </nav>


        <div ng-repeat="perf in $ctrl.perfs">
            <div class="row cs-perfRow">
                <div class="col-sm-10 cs-leftcol">
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="cs-perfDesc">{{perf.perf_desc}</div>   
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/angular-material/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.1/angular-material.min.css">

    <script src="Scripts/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-messages.min.js"></script>



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="perf-list.componentV3.js"></script>
    <link href="perfList.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
    hello2
    <div ng-cloak="" class="navBardemoBasicUsage" ng-app="perfList">
                <perf-list></perf-list>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please create a fiddle/plnkr to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter replaces your array with the filtered array:

```
this.perfs = myFilter;
```

So after a click to the first button, the array only contains one element, and the others are lost. After a click to the second button, it doesn't contain anything anymore.

Use a real angular filter (i.e. `ng-repeat="perfs | filter:byPerfNo"`), or store the filtered array in a **different** field of the component, and iterate on that different variable:

```
this.filteredPerfs = perfs;

this.myFunc = function(perfNo) {
    this.filteredPerfs = this.perfs.filter(function (el) { 
        return (el.perf_no === perfNo); 
    });
}

<div ng-repeat="perf in $ctrl.filteredPerfs">
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks. This was exactly what I was looking for.